# LAMP installation

Tags: mysql, lamp, localhost

I am trying to install LAMP server on my Ubuntu 14.10 but i am having a lot of problems:
the first time i installed it i tried to run my website locally but i wasn't able to access the database (mysql) knowing that i was sure of the correct password.
the second time i installed LAMP i wasn't able to locate the localhost directory
the third time i installed LAMP i couldn't even reach my database knowing that i  have created one in mysql.

please help me with this i am trying this for the past 5 days and it wont work.
Can you please provide me with the proper installation procedure.

I need to deploy a website file on a localhost server and connect it to mysql database . i am using all types of languages in the website.

regards,
Georges.

Answer (score 0):

for Lamp installation with best configuration:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

for project configuration my recommendation for you [ubuntu documentation](http://help.ubuntu.com)

Comment: That can be done shorter ;)

Comment: tasksel include Best configuration for this installation

Comment: The ^ makes it a tasksel installation ;-)